# Google chart not working. How to resolve?

Tags: charts

chart.googleapis.com deprecated | not working

I was using this function in google sheet

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&choe=UTF-8&chl=Distributor=JAY.MATA.DI.ENTERPRISES/RegNo=MH06AQ8431

Comment: The link you provided doesn't seem to work, not sure if that's usefull for the question

Answer (score 0):

On Google Developers site: [Image Charts/Image](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) there's a header, announcing:

> Warning: This API is deprecated and is scheduled to be turned off on March 14, 2019. Please use the actively maintained Google Charts API instead.

The "Google Charts API" points to the new API: https://developers.google.com/chart/

Beeing unable to see what your function was doing, I'm not sure how to build it in the new API.